# Android Autobrightness that works immediately

Tags: android, automation, android-sensors, brightness

It's pretty easy to set the autoBrightness in Android, isn't it?

```
Settings.System.putInt(resolver,
        Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, 0); // 0 is manual, 1 is auto
```

But if you are toggling:

```
boolean isAuto = Settings.System.getInt(resolver, 
        Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE) == 1;
Settings.System.putInt(resolver,
        Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, isAuto ? 0 : 1);
```

It won't automatically adapt until you lock the screen and lock it again.

Comment: What about putting `isAuto ? 0 : 1` in its own () maybe...?

Comment: Not too sure if that would make a difference or not.

Comment: isAuto?0:1 is a ternary (boolean) expresion, it will be exactly the same with or without parentheses, but it's cleaner with. I was just writing quickly, as this is a question-answer i wanted to share because it was driving me crazy for weeks :-)

Comment: Ok, I know the expresion but I wasn't sure if the () made a difference. It does seem odd that it wouldn't work the way you had it in your question...

Comment: It actually sets the setting right in the settings menu, if you monitor it, you can see that the setting is changed. However, the brightness is not adapted instantly, instead you must lock and unlock the screen to take effect. Putting it to manual again before auto, causes it to apply directly (don't quite know why)

Comment: Interesting... I'll keep that in mind. Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but setting it again to 0 before setting it to 1 works:

```
boolean isAuto = Settings.System.getInt(resolver, 
    Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE) == 1;
if (isAuto) {
    Settings.System.putInt(resolver,
        Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, 0); // set to 0 again, even if it is already 0
    Settings.System.putInt(resolver,
        Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, 1); // now it auto-adapts
} else {
    Settings.System.putInt(resolver,
         Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, 0);
}
```